# Django celery - Restart the task when it's completed

Tags: django, redis, celery

```
    @app.task
    def Task1():
        print("this is task 1")
        return  "Task-1 Done"
```

Just take an example I want to restart the task when it's completed

Comment: Do you mean to just restart the same task always? So something like an infinite loop? Or are there any conditions before it should be restarted such as an error occurred, or a specific input to the task meets a particular criteria, etc.?

Comment: I added an answer on how you would automatically restart the same task once completed. Does it answer your question?

Comment: @NielGodfreyPonciano Thanks for the response, Let's suppose I am calling task add two number.
` @app.task
def add(x, y):
    return x + y
`
when I call it using delay I got a unique AsyncResult 
add.delay(4,4)
<AsyncResult: b25ec3d1-fce0-4e04-9031-a365ec6d96c3>
add.delay(4,4)
<AsyncResult: bff65fd0-b51b-4394-aa76-4186335e54ff>
my question is that can we reput/restart the same instance into the queue

Comment: In my answer, Option 2 and Option 3 meets what you need. I updated the answer to include logs that will show that the same task id instance of the same queue is triggered for every restart. Could you check and verify if it already answers your question?

Comment: Based on your reply here in the comments, it seems that what you want is manually call the task multiple times and use the same instance every time. I updated the answer below on how you can do this with `apply_async` as it is not possible with `delay`. Hope this is what you need.

Comment: @NielGodfreyPonciano It helps me a lot, I appreciate your help thank you so much.

Comment: Glad it helped :) If it's all the answer that you are finding, you might want to accept it as the correct answer https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers otherwise leave it as is :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Manual consecutive calls

If you want to call the task multiple times and make it use the same task id every time, you can use the `task_id` argument of [apply_async](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/reference/celery.app.task.html#celery.app.task.Task.apply_async).

Note that this is not applicable with [delay](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/reference/celery.app.task.html#celery.app.task.Task.delay) as documented:

> delay(*args, **kwargs)
>
> - Star argument version of apply_async().
> - **Does not support the extra options enabled by apply_async().**

```
@app.task(bind=True)
def Task1(self):
    print(f"this is task 1 {self.request.id}")
```

```
>>> from tasks import Task1
>>> result = Task1.apply_async()
>>> result
<AsyncResult: ba488582-9d7d-4bda-a19d-a2b0bf9b503f>
>>> result.id
'ba488582-9d7d-4bda-a19d-a2b0bf9b503f'
>>> Task1.apply_async(task_id=result.id)
<AsyncResult: ba488582-9d7d-4bda-a19d-a2b0bf9b503f>
>>> Task1.apply_async(task_id=result.id)
<AsyncResult: ba488582-9d7d-4bda-a19d-a2b0bf9b503f>
>>> Task1.apply_async(task_id=result.id)
<AsyncResult: ba488582-9d7d-4bda-a19d-a2b0bf9b503f>
>>>
```

```
[2021-08-12 08:24:31,537: INFO/MainProcess] Task tasks.Task1[ba488582-9d7d-4bda-a19d-a2b0bf9b503f] received
[2021-08-12 08:24:31,538: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-4] this is task 1 ba488582-9d7d-4bda-a19d-a2b0bf9b503f
[2021-08-12 08:24:31,539: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-4] 

[2021-08-12 08:24:31,539: INFO/ForkPoolWorker-4] Task tasks.Task1[ba488582-9d7d-4bda-a19d-a2b0bf9b503f] succeeded in 0.00041928999962692615s: None
[2021-08-12 08:25:00,608: INFO/MainProcess] Task tasks.Task1[ba488582-9d7d-4bda-a19d-a2b0bf9b503f] received
[2021-08-12 08:25:00,609: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-4] this is task 1 ba488582-9d7d-4bda-a19d-a2b0bf9b503f
[2021-08-12 08:25:00,609: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-4] 

[2021-08-12 08:25:00,609: INFO/ForkPoolWorker-4] Task tasks.Task1[ba488582-9d7d-4bda-a19d-a2b0bf9b503f] succeeded in 0.0002528750001147273s: None
[2021-08-12 08:25:06,137: INFO/MainProcess] Task tasks.Task1[ba488582-9d7d-4bda-a19d-a2b0bf9b503f] received
[2021-08-12 08:25:06,139: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-4] this is task 1 ba488582-9d7d-4bda-a19d-a2b0bf9b503f
[2021-08-12 08:25:06,139: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-4] 

[2021-08-12 08:25:06,139: INFO/ForkPoolWorker-4] Task tasks.Task1[ba488582-9d7d-4bda-a19d-a2b0bf9b503f] succeeded in 0.0003467680007815943s: None
[2021-08-12 08:25:10,537: INFO/MainProcess] Task tasks.Task1[ba488582-9d7d-4bda-a19d-a2b0bf9b503f] received
[2021-08-12 08:25:10,539: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-4] this is task 1 ba488582-9d7d-4bda-a19d-a2b0bf9b503f
[2021-08-12 08:25:10,539: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-4] 

[2021-08-12 08:25:10,539: INFO/ForkPoolWorker-4] Task tasks.Task1[ba488582-9d7d-4bda-a19d-a2b0bf9b503f] succeeded in 0.0006299719998423825s: None
```

- The task id is the same for all executions, which here is `ba488582-9d7d-4bda-a19d-a2b0bf9b503f` (as visible in the `AsyncResult` as well)

---

## Automatic consecutive calls

If you want to keep on restarting the task, here are some options. All options below are infinitely recursive. You might want to put some conditions within the task about when the endless loop would be terminated, such as adding an input to the task and using it as basis if the execution must already stop.

**Option 1:** Call the task itself [asynchronously](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/userguide/calling.html#basics) within the same task. This is somewhat recursion-like. This would use the same task id as how it was done in the **Manual consecutive calls** (see above).

```
@app.task(bind=True)
def Task1(self):
    print(f"this is task 1 {self.request.id}")
    time.sleep(2)
    print("re-trigger task 1")
    Task1.apply_async(task_id=self.request.id)
```

**Option 2:** Trigger the [retry](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/userguide/tasks.html#retrying) mechanism provided by celery. This will use the same task id on the same queue as documented in that link:

> When you call retry it’ll send a new message, using the same task-id,
> and it’ll take care to make sure the message is delivered to the same
> queue as the originating task.

We can verify this by [displaying the task id](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/faq.html#can-i-get-the-task-id-of-the-current-task) via `self.request.id`.

```
@app.task(
    bind=True,
    default_retry_delay=0.1,
    retry_backoff=False,
    max_retries=None,
)
def Task1(self):
    print(f"this is task 1 {self.request.id}")
    time.sleep(2)
    print("re-trigger task 1")
    raise self.retry()
```

**Option 3:** Retry only for a [specific scenario](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/userguide/tasks.html#automatic-retry-for-known-exceptions) (here is `RestartTaskNeeded`). Same with **Option 2**, this will also use the same task id on the same queue.

```
class RestartTaskNeeded(Exception):
    pass


@app.task(
    bind=True,
    autoretry_for=(RestartTaskNeeded,),
    default_retry_delay=0.1,
    retry_backoff=False,
    max_retries=None,
)
def Task1(self):
    print(f"this is task 1 {self.request.id}")
    time.sleep(2)
    print("re-trigger task 1")
    raise RestartTaskNeeded
```

**Output:**

```
>>> from tasks import Task1
>>> Task1.apply_async()
<AsyncResult: 999e9de0-292f-412d-a9a8-b5c0013bdab3>
```

```
[2021-08-12 07:51:29,783: INFO/MainProcess] Task tasks.Task1[999e9de0-292f-412d-a9a8-b5c0013bdab3] received
[2021-08-12 07:51:29,785: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-1] this is task 1 999e9de0-292f-412d-a9a8-b5c0013bdab3
[2021-08-12 07:51:29,785: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-1] 

[2021-08-12 07:51:31,796: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-1] re-trigger task 1
[2021-08-12 07:51:31,797: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-1] 

[2021-08-12 07:51:31,820: INFO/MainProcess] Task tasks.Task1[999e9de0-292f-412d-a9a8-b5c0013bdab3] received
[2021-08-12 07:51:31,820: INFO/ForkPoolWorker-1] Task tasks.Task1[999e9de0-292f-412d-a9a8-b5c0013bdab3] retry: Retry in 0.1s: RestartTaskNeeded()
[2021-08-12 07:51:32,020: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-1] this is task 1 999e9de0-292f-412d-a9a8-b5c0013bdab3
[2021-08-12 07:51:32,020: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-1] 

[2021-08-12 07:51:34,023: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-1] re-trigger task 1
[2021-08-12 07:51:34,023: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-1] 

[2021-08-12 07:51:34,028: INFO/ForkPoolWorker-1] Task tasks.Task1[999e9de0-292f-412d-a9a8-b5c0013bdab3] retry: Retry in 0.1s: RestartTaskNeeded()
[2021-08-12 07:51:34,028: INFO/MainProcess] Task tasks.Task1[999e9de0-292f-412d-a9a8-b5c0013bdab3] received
[2021-08-12 07:51:36,031: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-1] this is task 1 999e9de0-292f-412d-a9a8-b5c0013bdab3
[2021-08-12 07:51:36,031: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-1] 

[2021-08-12 07:51:38,034: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-1] re-trigger task 1
[2021-08-12 07:51:38,034: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-1] 

[2021-08-12 07:51:38,038: INFO/ForkPoolWorker-1] Task tasks.Task1[999e9de0-292f-412d-a9a8-b5c0013bdab3] retry: Retry in 0.1s: RestartTaskNeeded()
[2021-08-12 07:51:38,039: INFO/MainProcess] Task tasks.Task1[999e9de0-292f-412d-a9a8-b5c0013bdab3] received
[2021-08-12 07:51:40,041: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-1] this is task 1 999e9de0-292f-412d-a9a8-b5c0013bdab3
[2021-08-12 07:51:40,042: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-1] 

[2021-08-12 07:51:42,044: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-1] re-trigger task 1
[2021-08-12 07:51:42,045: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-1] 

[2021-08-12 07:51:42,049: INFO/ForkPoolWorker-1] Task tasks.Task1[999e9de0-292f-412d-a9a8-b5c0013bdab3] retry: Retry in 0.1s: RestartTaskNeeded()
[2021-08-12 07:51:42,051: INFO/MainProcess] Task tasks.Task1[999e9de0-292f-412d-a9a8-b5c0013bdab3] received
[2021-08-12 07:51:44,050: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-1] this is task 1 999e9de0-292f-412d-a9a8-b5c0013bdab3
[2021-08-12 07:51:44,051: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-1] 

[2021-08-12 07:51:46,052: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-1] re-trigger task 1
[2021-08-12 07:51:46,052: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-1] 

[2021-08-12 07:51:46,057: INFO/ForkPoolWorker-1] Task tasks.Task1[999e9de0-292f-412d-a9a8-b5c0013bdab3] retry: Retry in 0.1s: RestartTaskNeeded()
[2021-08-12 07:51:46,058: INFO/MainProcess] Task tasks.Task1[999e9de0-292f-412d-a9a8-b5c0013bdab3] received
[2021-08-12 07:51:46,681: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-1] this is task 1 999e9de0-292f-412d-a9a8-b5c0013bdab3
[2021-08-12 07:51:46,681: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-1] 

[2021-08-12 07:51:48,682: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-1] re-trigger task 1
[2021-08-12 07:51:48,683: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-1] 

[2021-08-12 07:51:48,687: INFO/ForkPoolWorker-1] Task tasks.Task1[999e9de0-292f-412d-a9a8-b5c0013bdab3] retry: Retry in 0.1s: RestartTaskNeeded()
[2021-08-12 07:51:48,688: INFO/MainProcess] Task tasks.Task1[999e9de0-292f-412d-a9a8-b5c0013bdab3] received

... and so on ...
```

- The task always (automatically) "restarts" after completion
- The task id is the same for all executions, which here is `999e9de0-292f-412d-a9a8-b5c0013bdab3` (as visible in the `AsyncResult` as well)

---

## Further Reading

Depending on your exact purpose for this question, you might also be interested with Celery canvas e.g. chaining of tasks (calling a task after the completion of another task, the tasks maybe different or maybe the same).

- https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/getting-started/next-steps.html#chains
- https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/canvas.html#canvas-chain